# How can i separate Time and Date in two labels? my code shows both time and date in 1 label

Tags: vb6, utc

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Dim datUTC As Date

datUTC = Time_LocalToUTC(Now)

Me.lblCurrentTimeActual.Caption = Now
Me.lblUTCTimeActual.Caption = CStr(datUTC)
Me.lblPhilippinesTimeActual.Caption = 
CStr(DateAdd("h", 8, datUTC))


End Sub

Public Function Time_LocalToUTC(ByVal 
the_date As Date) As Date
On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
' Create a new instance of the WScript 
Shell
Dim oWshshell As Variant
Dim UTCOffset As Long

Set oWshshell = 
CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

' Copy the Universal Time clock offset from 
    the registry this does account for daylight 
    savings

```
UTCOffset = oWshshell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
```

'Take the present system time and add in the UTC offset from the registry. The 1440 is produced
  'by taking 60 * 24 since the units for a day have 1 equaling a day
      Time_LocalToUTC = the_date + (UTCOffset / 1440)
     GoTo EndCleanup
     ErrorTrap:
     MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, 
     vbOKCancel, "Error Getting UTC Time"

```
 EndCleanup:
 Set oWshshell = Nothing
 End Function[enter image description here] 
 [1]
```

Comment: `Now` will show both date and time. `Date` will show just the date, and `Time` will show just the time. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338033(v=vs.60).aspx) the link to the VB6 language reference, in case you haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Label1.Caption = Format$(CStr(DateAdd("h", 8, 
 datUTC)), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
 Me.Label2.Caption = Format$(CStr(DateAdd("h", 8, 
 datUTC)), " mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

this solved it. lol